# MongoDB Data Modeling Client Side User Permissions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, data-modeling

I was wondering if anyone had any input on improving a schema design.

In this system there is a user object which allows for linking/sharing account privileges with other accounts

(Think Gmail switching accounts, but being able to switch into your family/friend's accounts and perform actions on their account with limitations)

My current implementation is as follows (This is slightly simplified):

```
{
    user: ObjectId, // Refers to the owner of the account
    collaborator: ObjectId, // Refers to the person you invited with limited permissions.
    read_permissions: [], // Array of all routes the collaborator has read-only access for
    write_permissions: [] // Array of all routes the collaborator has full access for
}
```

There is an index on { user : 1, collaborator : 1 } , since all common queries involve verifying the relationship between the user and collaborator.

read_permissions and write_permissions are both a 1:many relationship.  Expected to be about 20-50 routes total that a user may restrict.

If a user has write_permissions, it is assumed they have read_permissions for that route as well.

The NodeJS implementation of this involves a Middleware check which will immediately return a 401 UNAUTHORIZED if the logged in user lacks permissions to perform a task.

A user is assigned a token for their own account, as well as a different token when logging into someone else's account.  If the user is logged into their own account, we know they have valid permissions.

If they are logged into an account where they have limited permissions, the middleware check passes the route of the action they are taking - and verifies they have read_permissions if the type is a GET request and write_permissions if the type is a PUT or POST request.

I'm mainly looking for feedback as to if this is a good approach and if I missed anything.  I couldn't find too many examples of data modeling approaches out there - especially something similar.

Thanks